# In Order object status pick list , how to set draft as default

Tags: visualforce

in order object  status having two fields 1.Draft 2.Activated how to set Draft field value in default

Comment: In visualforce page??

Answer (score 3):

edit the property of **Draft** value on **status** picklist you will get a checkdbox to make it default